# How can I get PyCharm/IDEA to run inspections (error highlighting) less frequently?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

PyCharm runs inspections very frequently which is annoying because it flashes various highlighting and errors on and off as you type the line and lags slightly.

I would like inspections to run either:

- on save only

or

- after `x` seconds idle

Either would be fine.

Comment: I would create an issue for that

Answer (score 2):

Check Settings | Editor | Autoreparse delay and set it to X*1000.

Comment: This affects more than error highlighting; it stops things like the selected object highlighting from being applied or removed in a timely manner.

Comment: That's wrong and should be fixed. Reported as http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124710